# How to determine how strings will be assigned to specific variables with input() and .split()

Tags: string, python-2.7, split

So I have written this code:

```
title, name = input("Please provide your title and name: ").split()
```

if I were to input say, `mr fabulous`, then `mr` and `fabulous` would be assigned to `title` and `name` accordingly, however, what if I were to just write `fabulous` and want it to be assigned to `name` instead of `title`?

Am i tackling this in the wrong way? Is there another way to do this with just one `input()` command? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will throw an exception.  I Also think you also want `raw_input` in stead of `input`, as the latter will try to process your input as a python command, and the former will process it as a string.

```
>>>title, name = raw_input("Please provide your title and name: ").split()
Please provide your title and name: fabulous
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Python's sytax to assign multiple variables simultaneously works when the number of variables matches the number of values in the given utterable.

As you can see the best way to get to the bottom of this is usually to just go for it and see what happens!

Now as for a suggestion for how to handle your input maybe something like this:

```
user_input = raw_input("Please provide your title and name: ").split()
if len(user_input) > 1:   # at least two entries provided
    title = user_input[0] # the first is the title
    name = user_input[1]  # the second is the name
elif len(user_input) > 0: # one input provided
    title = ""        # Or another default
    name = user_input[0]  # assign to name
print title,name
```

Sample output:

```
Please provide your title and name: mr fabulous
mr fabulous

Please provide your title and name: fabulous
 fabulous
```

Comment: ahh I see, so is there another way I can be tackling this so that if there is a space in the input, the first word goes to 'title', second word goes to 'name', otherwise if just one word, that goes to 'name'?

EDIT: Oh thank you so much! I think that will work perfect :)

Comment: yep, just saw it now, and it's exactly what i needed, thank you so much again :)

Comment: @jaceacewelfare no problem, glad to help.  I hope it should make it clear how to explicitly check user input in similar ways, but often just trying and seeing the error can provide the best lesson.